# Symfony2 Optional host in routing.yml

Tags: symfony, subdomain

I'm developing a website for the organisation I work for. Our main site is `www.mainsite.com`, but we have a few sub sites that "inherit" (each site accesses the same data and controllers, just look different) the main website. For example `sub1.mainsite.com`, `sub2.mainsite.com` etc.

I've started writing the code for the main website, and using the new subdomain/hosts routing feature of Symfony 2.2 I hoped to be able to programatically change the look of the website depending on the subdomain.

If I add `host: "{site}.mainsite.com"` to one of my routes, I can successfully get `{site}` in my controller. However, if there is no subdomain, the route isn't matched. This could be solved by adding a new route with no `host` option, but that would mean I double my routes, and I really don't want to have to do that.

In essence, all I really need is to be able to change the look of the website and the menu it uses based on a subdomain (or no subdomain).

Does anyone know how I can do this?

An example route:

```
news:
    pattern:  /news/{page}
    host: "{site}.mainsite.com"
    defaults: { _controller: MainSiteNewsBundle:News:index, page: 1, site:main }
    requirements:
        page:  \d+
        site: sub1|sub2
```

Also, as an aside, if *I could* get this to work, could I apply this rule site-wide without having to modify every one of my routes?

Comment: This is now a feature request: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7306